# What operations must be implemented for the List Abstract Data Type

Tags: language-agnostic, abstract-data-type

I understand what an Abstract Data Type (ADT), and how Concrete Data Types are used to implement them. How do languages like Java decide what methods they need to implement for the List ADT when designing an Array List for example. Are there a set number of operations for the List Abstract Data Type that any language must implement and does it matter what the language calls them?

Comment: There is no supreme court of programming terminology, or anything equivalent to that, so there cannot be one definitive list of what operations *must* be implemented for something to be called a "list". Nor can there be one definitive name for each operation according to its behaviour. There are conventions, but none is universally followed; some popular languages like Javascript and PHP flout such conventions by calling things "arrays" which certainly would not be called "arrays" outside the context of those languages, for example.

Comment: Thank you. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I can accept it for you. @kaya3